# Add Custom button at end of fields in Jquery - jTable Create/Update mode like submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-jtable

At jquery- jTable we can have some fields and actions .  I need Other button [possible at end of page]  near by Jquery JTable button("Submit" button)  that after on Click , run another function . so 
this is my code :

```
    $('#RequestSubmitDiv').jtable({
            title: 'newRec',
            paging: false,
            sorting: false,
            selecting:false; 
            selectingCheckBoxes:false,
            selectOnRowClick:false,
            jqueryuitheme:true,
            formCreated:function(event,data){
                 data.form.validationEngine();
            },
            formSubmitting:function(event,data){
               ...
               ...
            },
            formClode: function(d,e){...} ,                

            actions: {
                createAction: '/Adminsec/ManageAssets.aspx/CreateOrUpdate',
           //---not need below
                //listAction: '/Adminsec/ManageAssets.aspx/List',
                //updateAction: '/Adminsec/ManageAssets.aspx/CreateOrUpdate',
                //deleteAction: '/Adminsec/ManageAssets.aspx/Deletes'

  //-!!---Other Button and Action Need ---!!
                CustomAction:{
                  title:'RefreshNew',
                  sorting:false,
                  create:false,
                  edit:false ,
                  list:false ,
                  display:function(data){
                    return '<input type='button' id='MyBtn' onclick='Call_Mehod();>';                              
                   }

                 }
            },

            fields: {
              ID {title:'pk',type:'textarea'} , 
              RequestNO{type:'textarea'},
              description{type:'textarea'}
            }
        });
```

How can i add some button to Jquery- Jtable and call function ? 
these buttons don't repeat at rows or column , i mean it should be One instance after fields scope.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstood but if you want to add a button on each row, you can use [`display` property](http://www.jtable.org/apireference#fopt-display) of the field. I created a dummy field and added the display property. Somthing like this:

```js
...
Other: {
    title: 'Other',
    display: function (data) {
       return '<b>test</b>';
    },
    create: false,
    edit: false

}
...
```

However, if you wanted to add a general feature (i.e. single button for the table) , you can take a look at the [`toolbar` property](http://www.jtable.org/apireference#genopt-toolbar).

Answer (score 4):

I did as follow. The tag `<button>` and `class="jtable-command-button"` are always required. The next step is your class for icon and finally the event.

```
actions: {
                    title: 'Actions',
                    width: '1%',
                    sorting: false,
                    create: false,
                    edit: false,
                    list: true,
                    display: function (data) {
                        if (data.record) {
                            // This if you want a custom edit action.
                            return '<button title="Edit" class="jtable-command-button jtable-edit-command-button" onclick="alert(' + data.record.id + '); return false;"><span>Edit</span></button>';
                        }
                    }
                }
```