# enable/disable 'add new' button in jquery jtable

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, jsp, jquery-jtable

I am using jquery jtable to display tables from mysql db. In one of the tables, I want user to be allowed to insert only one row. i.e. disable `add new record` button once first row is inserted.

Is it possible to do this?

I have following structure defined for jtable:

```
$('#SchoolTableContainer').jtable({
    title : 'Schools List',
    paging: true, //Enable paging
    pageSize: 10, //Set page size (default: 10)
    sorting: true, //Enable sorting
    defaultSorting: 'name ASC', //Set default sorting
    actions : {
            listAction : 'ControllerAdminSchool?action=list',
            createAction : 'ControllerAdminSchool?action=create',
            updateAction : 'ControllerAdminSchool?action=update',
            deleteAction : 'ControllerAdminSchool?action=delete'
    },
    fields : {
            id : {
                title : 'School Id',
                key : true,
                list : false
            },
            name : {
                title : 'Name'
            },
            address : {
                title : 'Address'
            },
            email : {
                title : 'Email'
            },
            phone : {
                title : 'Phone'
            },
            website : {
                title : 'Website'
            },
            remark : {
                title : 'remark'
            }
    }
  });
  $('#SchoolTableContainer').jtable('load');
```

Similarly can enable/disable `edit` & `delete` buttons individually for each row depending upon some condition (e.g. if `name` has some particular value say `admin` then disable delete)?

Also how to add custom button in each row (e.g. to view details I can click on a `view` button and can view full details of corresponding row)?

Comment: Nobody have answer for this?

Answer (score 1):

- To dynamically disable the "add new record" functionality you can remove the button by defining a function handling the [recordsLoaded](http://jtable.org/ApiReference/Events#event-recordsLoaded) event:

  ```
  recordsLoaded: function(event, data) {
    var rowCount = data.records.length;
    if (rowCount>=1){
       $('#tableContainer').find('.jtable-toolbar-item.jtable-toolbar-item-add-record').remove();
    }
  }
  ```

similarly, to keep the behavior of your table coherent you should implement the same kind of logic for the events [rowInserted](http://jtable.org/ApiReference/Events#event-rowInserted) and [rowsRemoved](http://jtable.org/ApiReference/Events#event-rowsRemoved).

I'm aware that it's a DOM fiddling rather than controlling the behavior of jtable to stop offering the action, however hikalkan's (jtable's author) answer [here](https://github.com/hikalkan/jtable/issues/1294) leads me to believe it's the preferred approach.

- For the custom buttons on each row i normally implement the first solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18682294/add-custom-button-at-end-of-fields-in-jquery-jtable-create-update-mode-like-su).